# Extracting xml data with java

Tags: java, javascript, xml, html

I have written an app in Java to catalog thousands of educational resources on a shared directory. I have collected the information in XML files, for example:

```
<Resources>
   **<resource>**
      <name>resource_name</name>
      <path>path_to_resource</path>
      <subjects>
         <sub>ICT</sub>
         <sub>Maths</sub>
      </subjects>
      <topics>
         <top>functions_&amp;_formulae</top>
         <top>average(mean)</top>
     </topics>
     <!--more tags>
 **</resource>
   <resource>**
       <name>resource_two</name>
       <path>path_to_resource_two</path>
       <subjects>
         <sub>Literacy</sub>
       </subjects>
   <topics>
       <top>commas_in_a_list</top>
   </topics>
   <!--more tags>
```

The app allows users to tag and describe a resource according to subject, topic, level etc. Results are written to a full list of resources (as above) and also written out to specific subject related files. I have written XSL stylesheets to render these readable to users. I would like to create a filter so that a user can search for, e.g, "commas_in_a_list", which would return all the data for all resources with this as a tag value. I would like to display the data in a webpage. I'm not specifically looking for code here, but rather for advice. Can this be done with Java or would I be better off looking into Javascript or something else? Many thanks for your suggestions. Regards, John

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to serve this xml as is via rest or something and let the javascript client parse out the parts it needs.

Comment: I strongly recommend Dart language. More productive and fun than raw Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you will be needing all these technologies with Java being your predominant language for complex tasks.

For strong custom functionality i would recommend you to use [JavaWebParts taglib on Sourceforge](http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate.